# Make a new workbook with specific name

Tags: excel, vba

Need to make a new workbook with specific name but getting errors

```
Option Explicit

Sub teststs()

    Dim Path As String, DocName As String

    Path = "OS (C:)\Program Files\CODE"
    DocName = "dong"

    If Dir(Path & "\" & DocName & ".xlsx") = "" Then
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & "\" & DocName & ".xlsx"

    End If


End Sub
```

Bad File name or Number

Comment: That path looks fishy - specifically the OS and the parentheses around C:.

Comment: `Path = "OS (C:)\Program Files\CODE"` should most likely be `Path = "C:\Program Files\CODE"`

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment as answer:

```
Path = "OS (C:)\Program Files\CODE"
```

should most likely be:

```
Path = "C:\Program Files\CODE"
```

You should be able to open that up on its own in windows explorer; if it doesn't work, then it's not valid.